# Can't get any idea to deal with alphabetical pagination

Tags: python, web-scraping

So far when i worked with web scraping i found integers for pagination to increase or go on to the next page. Such as:

```
Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=1
Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=2
Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page=3
```

And I dealt those by using:

```
for i in range(1,4):
    url = "Los%20Angeles%2C%20CA&page={0}".format(i)
```

However, today i stumbled across alphabetical pagination and couldn't get any idea to increment it from A to B and so on. Example:

```
browse-business-directory/char:A
browse-business-directory/char:B
browse-business-directory/char:C
```

I'm using python to write my script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ord function in Python. Character 'a' has 97 as its value. So,

```
for i in range(97, 123):
    url = "browse-business-directory/char:{0}".format(chr(i))
```

Comment: Thanks blackmamba, for your reply. This is exactly what i was looking for.